# How to display data from my database in Slickgrid?

Tags: html, mysql, database, slickgrid

I started using Slickgrid recently but have not gotten in depth with it. I'm trying to connect it to my own MySQL database but I haven't gotten any luck doing so.

I want this for displaying purposes so all I need (for now) is to show up the data in the database into the Slickgrid.

Other than the connection to the database

```
var getDB = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var cntstring = "DSN=adsn;UID=root;PWD=1234";
getDB.Open(cntstring);
var rset = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
```

I don't know how to populate the rest to each cell in the Slickgrid.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? People are more likely to help if you show some sort of effort, such as your DB schema, front end, or back end code, etc...

Comment: we could help you if you show us what you have and the error...

Comment: @spryno724 other than the connection, I don't know where to edit to do a for loop and populate the data to the grid

Comment: @jcho360 I don't have an error, I just don't know where to go to start getting the data from the DB

Comment: you should start reading client-server technology, after that some PHP or another server language.

Comment: @jcho360 if you read my post properly, I'm asking how to do it. You could just be helpful and give a tutorial or something.

Comment: Just try a Google search for it: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql+slickgrid+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Build a grid with sample data first.  Get it working the way you want first.  Then retrieve data from the DB and format it like the sample data.

Comment: The thing is that sample data is not good, I want to get it straight from the DB. So starting from blank or with preloaded sample data makes no difference.
My question is how do I get it from the DB? All the data is there already.